# API switch triggers StrictMode policy violation

Tags: android

say, I'm halfway with Android 2.3.3 and then I find some APIs which I need but are only supported in Android 4.0. Thus, I switch to Android 4.0 by checking a different Project Build Target. Now here comes a `StrictMode policy violation, policy=2711, violation=1` which will go away when I switch back. So I think the switch is to blame but is there a way to work around this instead of building a new project?

**Updates**:
Even if I start a new project  with Android 4.0 but with the same codes, still `Strict policy violation`

Answer (score 0):

`StrictMode policy violation, policy=2711, violation=1` seems to be a `StrictModeDiskWriteViolation`. A disk write violation occurs when you are performing disk writes on the main UI thread. To solve it, you need to move the disk writes off the main thread. In this case it could be that some Android functionality that has changed in 4.0 and now includes disk writes, meaning you need to change your code such that you no longer use that functionality on the main thread in 4.0.

Can you post the full stack trace? That should have details about what is happening.

This link may also be helpful:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=10b73a621438323f

Comment: the problem weirdly goes away after I settling another one: INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. I just don't get it

Comment: Depends on what functions the internals are hitting... could be different paths for different situations. Stack trace will tell you what's the problem (see similar analysis in link above).